# Display instantly value in textbox using php

Tags: php, html

I have a textbox where the value is depends on the input type into it.

```
<input name="convertedcurrency" id="convertedcurrency" type="text" required="required"/>
```

Is there any possibility that using any PHP code to display the value of the typed value instantly? (I was trying to echo the value using php at another textbox.)

P/S: It must be a php code due to I need this value to combine with other php value for other use.

Comment: "It must be a php code" = wrong. This should be javascript/jquery. You could still use it with php.

Comment: you can use jquey for displaying the value instantly..

Comment: PHP is a server side scripting, that executes before your HTML is processed, so you have to rely on Javascript or equivalent which is a client side processing

Comment: "Display the value of the typed value instantly" by which you mean the page should not reload?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to do with php. You input is rendered and proceeded clientside (in the browser), so all manipulations should be done there too.

You should pass all the values and logic to the clientside, usually JavaScript, maybe with some sort of framework, jQuery, Angular.js, Ember.js, etc. Do manipulations there, and if you need to save something on the serverside, for example in the database - only then pass the data back using AJAX, and then you will need serverside processing with php, pyton, node.js, etc. Whatever is ok for you.